# How to pass hash table to azure child runbook using Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook powershell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, azure, workflow, runbook

How to pass hash table to azure child runbook using Start-`AzureRmAutomationRunbook` powershell `cmdlet`?

### I have two runbooks, test1 and test2:

```
workflow test1
    {
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint 

    $Hash = @{"ping"="pong"}
    $parameterHash = @{"Hash"="$Hash"}

    Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook `
        -ResourceGroupName "rg1" `
        -AutomationAccountName "ac1" `
        -Name "test2" `
        -Parameters $parameterHash 
    }
```

---

```
workflow test2
    {
    Param
        (  
        [Object]$Hash
        )     
        "Result1:"
        $Hash

        InlineScript {
            $Hash = $using:Hash

            "Result2:"
            $Hash

            "Result3:"
            foreach ($h in $Hash.GetEnumerator()) {
            Write-Host "$($h.Name): $($h.Value)"

            "Result4:"
            $HashType = $Hash.GetType()
            $HashType
            }
    }
}
```

---

When I run runbook test1, the result of runbook test2 is:

> Result1:
>
> System.Collections.Hashtable
>
> Result2:
>
> System.Collections.Hashtable
>
> Result3:
>
> Result4:
>
> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
>   PSComputerName
>   -------- -------- ----                                     --------                       --------------                 True     True     String                                   System.Object                  localhost
>
> Result4:
>
> True     True     String
>   System.Object                  localhost
>
> Result4:
>
> True     True     String
>   System.Object                  localhost

---

What is going wrong here? How do I properly pass a hash table to a azure child runbook using `Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook cmdlet`?

Thanx in advance!

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotations from "$hash". By adding quotes it turned your hashtable into a string. try this:

`$parameterHash = @{"Hash"=$Hash}`